# Gaps between sentences probably because of marginlabel. How to fix?

Tags: margins, marginpar

Gaps doesn't occur on every sentences but only to a few.

The MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, outer=3cm,%
inner=2cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=2cm, marginparsep=.4cm]
{geometry}

\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{romanian}
{\quotedblbase}
{\textquotedblright}
{\guillemotleft}
{\guillemotright}

%%% Comenzi personale
\newcommand{\gl}[1]{\enquote{#1}} % ghilimele
\newcommand{\ald}[1]{\textbf{#1}} % text aldin
\newcommand{\curs}[1]{\textit{#1}} % text cursiv

\newcommand\marginlabel[1]{\mbox{}\marginpar{\raggedright\hspace{1pt}#1}}
\newcommand{\bnote}[1]{\marginlabel{\small\curs{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Titlul}
\bnote{oximoron}Titlul operei lui Ion Creangă este alcătuit dintr-o
structură oximoronică ce desemnează condiția mezinului ajuns în
ipostaza de rob, dar și candoarea și originea nobilă a acestuia. De
asemenea, titlul înștiințează lectorul că firul narativ va contura
existența protagonistului.
\bnote{funcții: răufăcători, furnizori}
În raport cu condiția fiului de crai, personajele îndeplinesc anumite
funcții, I. Creangă plasând în universul său: răufăcători care,
producând un prejudiciu, trebuie rectificat de către erou, furnizorii
care oferă personajului principal un obiect miraculos și ajutoarele
care îl vor seconda pentru a finaliza o sarcină.

La temelia operei marelui prozator se afla o acțiune ce se deșterne
linear, iar succesiunea episoadelor este dispusă prin înlănțuire.
\bnote{formula inițială}
Creația debutează cu o formulă tipică
în care clipa efemeră se proiectează într-un illo tempore, iar
spațiul în care se desfășoară întâmplările este lipsit de contur
(\emph{\enquote{Amu cică era odată}}). Tot prin întrebuințarea
acestei \textbf{formule inițiale}, Creangă își introduce cititorul
în lumea basmului său, rupând astfel pârghiile realității în care
trăiește acesta.
\bnote{formula mediană}
Cu utilizarea \textbf{formulelor mediane}
(\emph{\enquote{Dumnezeu să ne ție, că
cuvântul din poveste, înainte mult mai este}} etc.) prozatorul va
realiza trecerea de la o secvență la alta, menținând simultan starea
de tensiune, de emoție, de incertitudine și curiozitate a cititorului.
\bnote{formula finală}Deznodământului îi corespunde \textbf{formula
finală} (\emph{\enquote{Și a ținut veselia ani întregi, și acum mai
ține încă;\dots}}) ce are menirea de a înștiința refacerea
echilibrului, readucând lectorul în lumea reală, făcându-l în a
reflecta profund asupra realității sociale.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add a `%` sign after `\bnote{...}` or continue immediately with the next word, like you did with your first `\bnote`.

Comment: @gernot Thanks a lot! So simple! Can you please explain me why a `%` removed the space? In the file there is no space between sentences..

Comment: The newline also counts as space. So you have one space before `\bnote` and one after it. The `%` sign comments out (removes) one of the newlines.